# How to work with cNFTs in Solana programs?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cnft

These are the 2 use-cases that I am looking for in my Solana program

- verify that a cNFT owner signed a transaction
- perform a Cross-Program-Invocation to the Bubblegum program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this repo to demonstrate this

https://github.com/Aiyualive/program-examples/tree/bob/cutils

As of posting this, it is currently being reviewed as a PR to the Solana program examples.